# When does Thread.sleep(1000) sleeps less than 1000 milliseconds?

Tags: multithreading, time, sleep

In this interesting article about [falsehoods programmers believe about time](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time-wisdom), one of them is

> Thread.sleep(1000) sleeps for >= 1000 milliseconds.

When isn't this true?

Comment: That seems a bit like a "programming folklore" list. While most of the stuff there is fairly obvious, I don't see any concrete evidence to back it up.

Comment: Let me add to this that a timer may fire slightly before the time is up.

Comment: The quote itself bears no meaning outside a Real-time OS. To answer the question w/ a simple scenario: the real-time clock can be adjusted, hence sleep less. The thread can experience sporadic wake-up due to OS signal is the next super-obvious case.

Comment: @bestsss - I forgot about Java's infamous spurious wakeups.

Comment: But it's not Java, it's an OS feature.

Comment: @bestsss - some API abstract over this OS feature, e.g. in C# there is no spurious wakeups AFAIK.

Comment: spurious wakeups come from linux/posix pthreads. Windows itself have issues w/ races too, i.e. `PulseEvent`. Overall having a non-racy wait/notify would just too expensive in the face of handling OS signals.

Comment: @Tudor there are detailed explanations of most of the falsehoods in the accompanying Reddit, Hacker News, BoingBoing and MetaFilter threads. I linked them from the post but for convenience here they are again: http://bit.ly/UsbA77 and http://bit.ly/LBEaJU and http://bit.ly/UsbNXX and http://bit.ly/LaJKYz and http://bit.ly/LBEaJU and http://bit.ly/NSuRpE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Implementation of the sleep by windows operating system, which is what Thread.sleep will call underneath): If dwMilliseconds is less than the resolution of the system clock, the thread may sleep for less than the specified length of time. If dwMilliseconds is greater than one tick but less than two, the wait can be anywhere between one and two ticks, and so on. To increase the accuracy of the sleep interval, call the [timeGetDevCaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to determine the supported minimum timer resolution and the [timeBeginPeriod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to set the timer resolution to its minimum.

Answer (score 5):

The OS only reacts at interrupts and therefore handles sleep expiries at the time of an interrupt. It is correct the the interrup frequency can be increased by means of `timeBeginPeriod`. The difficulty is that the expiry of the `Sleep()` function requires two conditions to be met:

1. An Interrupt has to occur
2. *dwMilliseconds* has to expire.

Condition 2 is the problem here. The *dwMilliseconds* will be compared to the expired system time at interrupts. The system time will cause the `Sleep()` function to expire in filetime-format increments, in other words when n times the system-time increment becomes larger than *dwMilliseconds*. Thus one may not be able to ever get 1ms sleep delays. This heavely depends on the systems hard- and software and configuration (system-time increment/granularity).

A closer look with some examples can be found [here](http://windowstimestamp.com/description)

To answer the question: Thread.sleep(1000) sleeps for >= 1000 milliseconds is always TRUE!
Edit: When executed right after a Thread.sleep(1)

Edit: However Thread.sleep(1) sleeps for >= 1 milliseconds may not always be TRUE

Comment: Can you clarify the part of the linked source that says Sleep(1) may return in under a millisecond? I read the source and it doesn't seem to say that at all.

Comment: @CameronBielstein: as written in the accepted answer here: _If dwMilliseconds is less than the resolution of the system clock, the thread may sleep for less than the specified length of time._